# SimpleDateFormat pattern based on locale, but forcing a 4-digit year

Tags: java, locale, simpledateformat

I need to build a date format like `dd/MM/yyyy`. It's almost like `DateFormat.SHORT`, but contains 4 year digits.

I try to implement it with

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd//MM/yyyy", locale).format(date);
```

However for US locale the format is wrong.

Is there a common way to format date that changes pattern based on locale?

Thank you

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do here: have different date formats for different locales, or have a formatting that is not affected by locale?

Comment: I am trying to have different date formats for different locales. For example, dd/MM/yyyy for European locales, MM/dd/yyyy for US locale

Comment: Please note, that not all european countries follow the `dd/mm/yyyy` pattern, quite a few use `dd.mm.yyyy` and some even `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: thanks, I just gave one of the examples

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
    FieldPosition yearPosition = new FieldPosition(DateFormat.YEAR_FIELD);

    StringBuffer format = dateFormat.format(date.getTime(), buffer, yearPosition);
    format.replace(yearPosition.getBeginIndex(), yearPosition.getEndIndex(), String.valueOf(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

    System.out.println(format);
```

Using a FieldPosition you don't really have to care about wheter the format of the date includes the year as "yy" or "yyyy", where the year ends up or even which kind of separators are used.

You just use the begin and end index of the year field and always replace it with the 4 digit year value and that's it.

Answer (score 5):

## java.time

Here’s the modern answer. IMHO these days no one should struggle with the long outdated `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Their replacement came out in the modern Java date & time API early in 2014, the [java.time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

I am just applying the idea from [Happier’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9461062/5772882) to the modern classes.

The [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.chrono.Chronology-java.util.Locale-) method generates a formatting pattern for date and time styles for a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). We manipulate the resulting pattern string to force the 4-digit year.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of( 2017, Month.JULY, 18 );

String formatPattern =
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        FormatStyle.SHORT, 
        null, 
        IsoChronology.INSTANCE, 
        userLocale);
formatPattern = formatPattern.replaceAll("\\byy\\b", "yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern, userLocale);

String output = date.format(formatter);
```

Example output:

- For `Locale.US`: `7/18/2017`.
- For each of `UK`, `FRANCE`, `GERMANY` and `ITALY`: `18/07/2017`.

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` allows us to get the localized format pattern string directly, without getting a formatter first, that’s convenient here. The first argument to `getLocalizedDateTimePattern()` is the date format style. `null` as second argument indicates that we don’t want any time format included. In my test I used a `LocalDate` for `date`, but the code should work for the other modern date types too (`LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`).

Answer (score 0):

I have similar way to do this, but I need to get the locale pattern for the ui controller.

So here's the code

```
            // date format, always using yyyy as year display
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
        SimpleDateFormat simple = (SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat;
        String pattern = simple.toPattern().replaceAll("\\byy\\b", "yyyy");
        System.out.println(pattern);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just use java.text.DateFormat class ?

```
DateFormat uk = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK);
DateFormat us = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.US);

Date now = new Date();
String usFormat = us.format(now);
String ukFormat = uk.format(now);
```

That should do what you want to do.

Comment: No, he wanted a localized DateFormat.SHORT pattern with a four digit year.

Comment: Right, I misread some of my code. In that case ... do that above (after replacing LONG with SHORT) ... then call toPattern() after casting the DateFormat to SimpleDateFormat and then search and replace the yy to yyyy. Then create a new SimpleDateFormat with the new string pattern.

Comment: Still wrong. You cannot expect the instance returned by DateFormat.getDateInstance to be of the type SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Thats wierd ... because the javadoc states "You can also set the time zone on the format if you wish. If you want even more control over the format or parsing, (or want to give your users more control), you can try casting the DateFormat you get from the factory methods to a **SimpleDateFormat**. This will work for the majority of countries; just remember to put it in a try block in case you encounter an unusual one."

Comment: What didn't you understand of "you can try ..." and "work for the majority ..."?

Comment: Have a look at the code in the DateFormat class ... **EVERY** available locale that is shipped with Java 6 returns a SimpleDateFormat instance. Yes it will cause a problem if you define your own locale and return an instance other than SimpleDateFormat .. but generally it will work.