# How to display the year in full when using localization in Java?

Tags: java, date, date-format

```
private String setDate(int day) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, + day);
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    String formattedDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
    return formattedDate;
}
```

The above method returns "14/06/12" for `Locale.UK` and "06/14/12" for `Locale.US`.

How can I get it to return the year in full, i.e. "14/06/2012" for the US locale and "06/14/2012" for UK locale?

Comment: String pattern = sdf.toPattern().replaceAll("y+","yyyy"); sdf.applyPattern(pattern);

Comment: @dragon66: you have the best answer so far - please post it as an answer.  You might like to include this note from the javadoc: *"If you want even more control over the format or parsing, (or want to give your users more control), you can try casting the `DateFormat` you get from the factory methods to a `SimpleDateFormat`. This will work for the majority of countries; just remember to put it in a `try` block in case you encounter an unusual one."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**JHS's** answer is almost complete. The only thing needs to be done is to make it work for all locales.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

class ChangeDateFormat
{
    private String setDate(int day, Locale locale) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +day);
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
        if (df instanceof SimpleDateFormat)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) df;
            // To show Locale specific short date expression with full year
            String pattern = sdf.toPattern().replaceAll("y+","yyyy");
            sdf.applyPattern(pattern); 
            return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        }
        String formattedDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
        return formattedDate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ChangeDateFormat cdf = new ChangeDateFormat();        
        System.out.println(cdf.setDate(1, Locale.JAPAN));
    }
}
```

Following **Greg's** comments (thanks Greg), here is the relevant note from the javadoc:

*"If you want even more control over the format or parsing, (or want to give your users more control), you can try casting the `DateFormat` you get from the factory methods to a `SimpleDateFormat`. This will work for the majority of countries; just remember to put it in a `try` block in case you encounter an unusual one."*

Comment: Nice one. `replace` instead of `concat`. It dint strike my mind because of the hurry. Good answer.

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796321/simpledateformat-pattern-based-on-locale seems to work for all countries.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to get the `locale` pattern and append the extra `yy` to the format.

This could help you -

```
private String setDate(int day) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(new Date());
  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, + day);    
  DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
  // code modified from here
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) df;
  sdf.applyPattern(sdf.toPattern().replace("yy","yyyy")); // replacing to yyyy
  String formattedDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
  return formattedDate;
}
```

This would work for all patterns which return a 2 digit year in the end.

I had `sdf.toPattern.concat("yy")` which would work for only those `Locale` who had `yy` in the end. However **Dragon66**'s idea to use `replace("yy", "yyyy")` would work for all `Locale`.

Comment: The original pattern, assuming it is a simple date format, does not necessarily end in `yy`.

Comment: The solution is for the combination of the `DateFormat int`and most of the `Locale` and for `Date` it ends in `yy`. Also I have added a line in the end - Only for patterns which has a 2 digit year in the end. For US and UK it is fine.

Comment: Thanks guys. very helpful. Although it is perfect for UK, US, it seems to fail for Locales that have the date start from year, e.g. Japan is 2012-06-14 and using the above solution I get 12-06-1412

Answer (score 0):

You have to hope that your `DateFormat` is an instance of `SimpleDateFormat`, so that you can obtain its pattern and change it from two to four years.

Comment: Thanks. But if I use a pattern and format it then it gives me either 2012 for a pattern of "yyyy" or if I use a pattern like "MM/dd/YYYY" is not desirable for UK, and the pattern "dd/MM/YYYY" is not desirable for US.

Comment: @AmirGhahrai It looks as if Juniad has explained it better than I did.